# Cumulative sum in MYSQL based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, window-functions

Let's say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE sales(
                      id serial PRIMARY KEY,
                      sales_employee VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                      fiscal_year INT NOT NULL,
                      sale DECIMAL(14,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO sales(sales_employee,fiscal_year,sale)
VALUES('Bob',2016,100),
      ('Bob',2017,150),
      ('Bob',2018,200),
      ('Alice',2016,150),
      ('Alice',2017,100),
      ('Alice',2018,200),
      ('John',2016,200),
      ('John',2017,150),
      ('John',2018,250);
```

How to I get the following result:

```
2016 Bob 100
2016 Alice 150
2016 John 200
2017 Bob 250
2017 Alice 250
2017 John 350
2018 Bob 450
2018 Alice 450
2018 John 600
```

The number of employees and years in real sample is much more.

Comment: Your sums are wrong for 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a window `sum` :

```sql
select s.*, sum(sale) over(partition by sales_employee order by fiscal_year) as running_sales
from sales s
order by fiscal_year, sales_employee
```

Comment: I found my problem, I didn't use `order by fiscal_year` inside over. Why if I remove it it produce not running sum but just sum for all times?

Comment: @ogbofjnr: yes, without an `order by` all sales in the `partition` will be sumed on each row. See by yourself : https://dbfiddle.uk/RnCsnDur